# Using QSerialPort on a separate thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, serial-port

I'm trying to read/write data from a separate thread. No error is displayed when opening the serial port but I'm unable to read or write anything.

Here is my *SerialThread.h* code:

```
#include <QThread>

class SerialThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SerialThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SerialThread();

protected:
    void run();
private:
    bool _threadRunning;
};
```

And my *SerialThread::run()* implementation :

```
void SerialThread::run()
{
    QSerialPort *_serial = NULL;
    foreach(QSerialPortInfo info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
        QString name = info.portName();
        if(name.startsWith("usbserial-"))
        {
            _serial = new QSerialPort(info, this);

            qDebug() << "Opening " << name;
            if(_serial->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite))
            {
                qDebug() << "ok";
                _threadRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }

    while(_threadRunning)
    {
        QByteArray array = _serial->read(10);
        for (int i = 0; i< array.length(); i++)
            qDebug() << QString::number(array[i], 16);
        msleep(1000);
    }

    if(_serial)
    {
        _serial->close();
        delete _serial;
    }
}
```

The same code works without thread (connecting the *readyReady()* signal).

Any idea? May I misuse the QThread object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` doesn't actually do any reading and needs a event queue to function properly

in a pinch you can call `_serial->waitForReadyRead()` whenever `_serial->bytesAvailable()` is 0